# CSS Minification causes IE9 to display urls next to all links on page

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, yui, minify

I have been experimenting with integrating some css minification tools into my site and I have had great luck except for a strange quirk that is happening in ie9 only. I am using the YUI compressor to optimize the css and no other browsers are having the issue that I am observing. When viewing any page on my site with ie9 the page will render correctly for a second and then it will immediately display the urls of every link on the page as an anchor tag next to the link. Naturally this looks like crap. Disabling the minification makes the problem go away and re-enabling brings it right back. I have never seen this before and I am uncertain why ie9 is behaving this way. I have used other css minification solutions to minify the css instead of YUI but I still experience the same symptom. Has anyone encountered this particular issue or have some insight in how to resolve it. I spent a better part of yesterday googling around but I admit I had difficulty knowing how to word it correctly in a way that would produce results. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well not even an hour after posting this I finally tracked down the cause of this wierd behavior. Apparently in my css there is a @media print rule that defined the following:
[code]
a:after{content:" (" attr(href) ")"}
[/code]
This is not supposed to be used obviously but either ie9 is misbehaving or the minification has mangled the [code]@media[/code] rule which is equally likely. So I answered my own question but I have to wait 8 hours to submit my answer.